# LTC6811 WRITE to ADG728 Switch/Multiplexer via I2C

Tags: c, i2c, battery

My setup includes a LTC6811 ([datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6811-1-6811-2.pdf)) and an ADG728 switch/multiplexer ([datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG728_729.pdf)). The goal is to read battery temperature data one at a time from a selected channel on the ADG728 switch/multiplexer via I2C.

The address of the switch/multiplexer is 0x4C. Below is the sequence that I put together.

> ICOM0[3:0]--0x6(START) , D0[7:4]--0x9(1001) , D0[3:0]--0x8(1000) ,
> FCOM0[3:0]--0x8(MASTER NACK)   (D0 as the mux 7-bits address + Write
> bit)
>
> ICOM1[3:0]--0x0(BLANK) , D1[7:4]--0x0(0000) , D1[3:0]--0x1(0001) ,
> FCOM1[3:0]--0x9(Master NACK + STOP)   (D1 as the mux channel:
> 0b00000001)

I package the sequences into tx_data array (refer to [DC2259](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/Linduino/blob/master/LTSketchbook/Part%20Number/6000/6811/DC2259/DC2259.ino) of LTSketchbook).

```
BMS_IC[current_ic].com.tx_data[0]= 0b01101001; // 0x69;
BMS_IC[current_ic].com.tx_data[1]= 0b10001000; // 0x88;
BMS_IC[current_ic].com.tx_data[2]= 0b00000000; // 0x00;
BMS_IC[current_ic].com.tx_data[3]= 0b00011001; // 0x19;
```

Then I call the WRCOMM and STCOMM (data length = 2) commands before I call ADAX and RDAUX commands to read the data from GPIO1. I would like to know whether there's anything wrong with the sequences above because I cannot read a valid value from GPIO1. Any thought or help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you fixed this problem?
I think you need a length of 3 to ensure i2c initialization. Fill the rest of data with "7" to ignore after "9".

[See datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZNuJ.png)